# How to use *ngIf on a material input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the same input 2 times. I want to show the first one on the first case and the second one on the second case. If I add `*ngIf` to my material input, it says "mat-form-field must contain a `MatFormFieldControl`.", but I have the mat-input right behind it (also tried it before `ngIf`)

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [style.width.%]="45">
  <mat-label>Phasenende</mat-label>
  <input
    *ngIf="this.projectPhases <= 1"
    matInput
    [min]="this.projectForm.controls['phases'].value[i].pStart"
    placeholder="Ende"
    [matDatepicker]="picker2"
    formControlName="pEnd"
  />
  <input
    *ngIf="this.projectPhases > 1"
    matInput
    [min]="this.projectForm.controls['phases'].value[i-1].pEnd"
    placeholder="Ende"
    [matDatepicker]="picker2"
    formControlName="pEnd"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: use <ng-container *ngif=... to wrap it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-container to wrap it:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [style.width.%]="45">
  <mat-label>Phasenende</mat-label>
  <!-- First case -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="this.projectPhases <= 1">
      <input matInput [min]="this.projectForm.controls['phases'].value[i].pStart" placeholder="Ende"       [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="pEnd">
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Second case -->
  <ng-container *ngIf="this.projectPhases > 1">
  <input matInput [min]="this.projectForm.controls['phases'].value[i-1].pEnd" placeholder="Ende" [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="pEnd">
  </ng-container>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because this.projectPhases is initially "undefined" and:

- undefined <= 1  --> false
- undefined > 1 --> false

Try with a default:

```
this.projectPhases = 0;
```

or wrap all in an:

```
*ngIf="projectPhases"
```

Answer (score -1):

For **ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.**
This Error If you have imported all MatModules,
Then check you don't have any ngIf inside input

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).